# Passing array of strings from C# to C++ Com

Tags: c#, com, interop

I have requirement of passing an array of strings from a C# module to my C++ COM component. The following is the idl declaration;

```
[id(11), helpstring("method deleteObjectsEx")] HRESULT deleteObjectsEx(
                [in] BSTR userName,
                [in] BSTR userPasswd, 
                [in] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) varValues, 
                [in] BSTR deleteMode
                );
```

And from the C# we use the following code to invoke the API

```
List<string> ObjectIDS = new List<string>();
ObjectIDS.Add(obj._ObjectId[0]);
ObjectIDS.Add(obj._ObjectId[1]);

/*Array ar = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), size);
ar.SetValue(obj._ObjectId[0], 0);
ar.SetValue(obj._ObjectId[1], 1);*/

mhubBridge.deleteObjectsEx(Encrypt(auth.UserName), 
                           Encrypt(auth.UserPassword), 
                           ObjectIDS.ToArray(),
                           obj._delMEthod);
```

On invoking the deleteObjectsEx API i get "A first chance exception of type 
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException occurred in IPDWebService.DLL
IPDWS::trace::(Tuesday, 06 August 2013 13:27): Exception in deleteObjectsEx:: message - Specified array was not of the expected type.`

Comment: What is the C# declaration of `deleteObjectsEx` ? (if you imported the .tlb, one has probably been auto-generated)

Comment: @Medinoc its public virtual void deleteObjectsEx(string userName, string userPasswd, Array varValues, string deleteMode);

Comment: @xantos Sorry for the extra code ...i was trying out different combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**not working**)

Try using the `ar` array.

```
mhubBridge.deleteObjectsEx(Encrypt(auth.UserName), 
                           Encrypt(auth.UserPassword), 
                           ar,
                           obj._delMEthod);
```

If it works, remove all the `ObjectIDS` "things".

or try:

(**working**)

```
object[] ar = new object[] { obj._ObjectId[0], obj._ObjectId[1] };
```

and pass it to the `deleteObjectsEx(...)`

because technically a `VARIANT` is an `object`, so a `SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)` is an `object[]`.

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar Try the `object[]` (second example). Remember to pass it to the `deleteObjectsEx`!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
object[] ar = new object[2];
ar [0] = obj._ObjectId[0];
ar [1] = obj._ObjectId[1];
```